# Probability Distribution: Verification of my Thinking

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

More than anything, I just need someone to confirm for me that I'm on the right track.

So I have a table that has some random variable *$X$* which has a probability distribution table of: 
\begin{array}{r|l}
x&P(X = x)\\\hline
2 & 0.15\\ 
3 & 0.25 \\
5 & 0.15 \\
7 & 0.10 \\
11 & 0.30 \\
13 & 0.05 
\end{array}
So would I find say $15$'s probability by adding the ones I have now then subtracting from $1$? And would that be the same process for any other ones I would need such as $23, 27$, etc.?

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: The given probabilities all add up to 1. These 6 numbers should encompass all the possible values $X$ can take with positive probability. So 15, 23, 27, and any other number should each have probability 0, unless there's something I'm not understanding here.

Comment: @srnoren Yeah, that makes sense there. I didn't realize they already add up to 1 till now. Over sight on my part. However, my question then is how would I say find the mean for Y = 2X + 1? Using the given table, that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't do that since for example $15$ is not in the range of your random variable. Thus, for example $P(X=15) = 0$.

You could define, for example a new random variable $S = X+Y+Z$, where $X,Y,Z$  are independent and follow the distribution you provide. Then for convenience (hehe), to get $S = 6$ you must get the unordered triple $(2,2,2)$.
Then 
$$P(S = 2) = (.15)^3 = 0.003375.$$

---

If you have $Y = 2X+1$, then to compute the mean

1. you could find the distribution of $Y$ and compute the mean using the usually formula;
2. let $\mathcal X$ be the set of possible values of $X$. Then
   $$E[Y] = \sum_{x\in \mathcal X} (2x+1)P(X = x)$$
3. you could use the properties of expectation and find
   $$E[Y] = E[2X+1] = 2E[X]+1.$$

Comment: Okay. So say if I were to find the mean for variable Y = 2X + 1. Would I then plug in 2X + 1 into the mean formula?

Comment: Okay but now the issue is that I'm a bit lost on finding the distribution table for $Y$ I know it's pertaining to some sort of linear transformation...

Comment: @Romana I updated my answer regarding the mean.